# How to fix error while importing Numexpr Python

Tags: python, numexpr

On Windows 10 Python 3.7.9 (IDLE) I successfully installed "pip install numexpr" but while "import numexpr as ne" I have an error:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#21>", line 267, in 
import numexpr as ne
File "C:\Python379\lib\site-packages\numexpr_*init*_.py", line 28, in 
from numexpr.interpreter import MAX_THREADS, use_vml, __ BLOCK_SIZE1__
ImportError: DLL load failed: Can't find this module.*

Maybe I need to install Numexpr other way

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same error. I fixed it by downloading numpy+mkl package from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) and pip installing it from terminal (from where the downloaded whl file is located)

Download the correct version that suits your configuration. I use python3.6 so I downloaded numpy‑1.19.5+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: I also fixed the same issue by the method. Thank you .